# Why is it that when i try to change a variable in this case statement it doesn't change the variable outside that loop

Tags: java, while-loop, scope, initialization

Why is this happening when I start(?, i just declared the name of the variable, I'm not sure what thats called too tired to kno) the variable outside of the case, why isn't it just changing the variable. It's not like I'm making an instance of it. Why should I have to make an instance of it? It seems like a simple thing i should be able to do. How do i go about getting around this without making any variable statics.

I have some code I was working on below, I think ill just leave it all in but look at the 3th case, when I try to run it the things I changed in the 2st case are not affect the variables such as names[] and `amouintOfNameds`;

code:

```
package comp1skeleton2015;

class InputOutput
{


    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        AQAConsole2015 console = new AQAConsole2015();
        AQAWriteTextFile2015 writeAQA = new AQAWriteTextFile2015();
        AQAReadTextFile2015 readAQA = new AQAReadTextFile2015();
        String doProgram = "yes";

        while(doProgram.equals("yes"))
        {
            String[] names;
            String fileOutput = "names.txt";
            int amountOfNames = 0;
            int amountOfNames2 = 0;
            int x = 0;
            names = new String[1];
            names[0] = "";

            console.println("Would you like to: ");
            console.println("1 - Write names to a file ");
            console.println("2 - Read names from a file ");
            console.println("3 - Display these names ");
            int option = console.readInteger("Please enter the corresponding number for the option: ");

            switch (option)
            {   
                case 1:
                {
                    int numOfNames = console.readInteger("Please enter how many names you would like to enter ");
                    names = new String[numOfNames];
                    writeAQA.openFile(fileOutput);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++)
                    {
                        String temp = console.readLine("Enter name " + i + ".");
                        writeAQA.writeToTextFile(temp);
                    }
                    writeAQA.closeFile();
                }
                break;
                case 2:
                {
                    readAQA.openTextFile(fileOutput);
                    boolean continueLoop = true;

                    while(readAQA.readLine() != null)
                    {
                        amountOfNames = amountOfNames + 1;
                    }

                    console.println (amountOfNames);
                    readAQA.closeFile();
                    readAQA.openTextFile(fileOutput);
                    names = new String[amountOfNames];

                    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfNames; i++)
                    {
                        names[i] = readAQA.readLine();
                    }
                    amountOfNames2 = amountOfNames;
                    readAQA.closeFile();
                }
                break;
                case 3:
                {
                    console.println (amountOfNames2);
                    console.println(names[1]);
                    for(int y = 0; y < amountOfNames; y++)
                    {
                        console.println(y + ": " + names[y]);
                    }
                }
                break;
                default:
                {   
                    console.println("You have entered an incorrect option, please try again");
                }
                break;

            }
            //doProgram = console.readLine("yes to continue");
        }
    }
}
```

that you very much for reading I hope to help you get by with them bye thanks.

Comment: in your while loop, you keep initializing your names variable.
declare and initialize 'names' outside of the loop.

Comment: Step through the code under the debugger.  Look at the variables when you believe they should change, and make sure that part of the code is actually executed.  Also make sure you're not inadvertently re-initializing data you want to keep.  The debugger is your Friend :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `while` loop and you take user input in every pass of the loop. So the user enters `2` in one pass of the loop, and you read the file and populate your variables. In the next pass of the loop, the user enters `3`, and you try to print these variables. Now the way while loop works is that it executes the piece of code inside the loop over and over again. After you populate your variables in `case 2`, the loop starts from the top and it finds variable declarations for `names`, `amountOfNames` etc. and it initialises them to empty, 0 etc.

If you want the changes made to these variables in one pass of the loop to be available in the next pass of the loop, you need to declare them outside the while loop.

Explaining the above in terms of variable scope: Though you've declared the variables outside the `case` statement, they are still *inside* the `while` loop, and that limits their *scope* to a single pass of the while loop. To increase their scope to multiple passes of the loop, they need to be declared outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String[] names;
        String fileOutput = "names.txt";
        int amountOfNames = 0;
        int amountOfNames2 = 0;
        int x = 0;
        names = new String[1];
        names[0] = "";
```

Declare all these variable outside do while loop. Whenever loop executes all of these variable initialize. If you want any variable to be initialize then keep those variables inside the loop else move the variable outside the loop to avoid reinitialization every time.

Answer (score 0):

You reset values after each loop iteration, and you don't print values outside of the case statement. Get some sleep, and re-read the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-initializing the variables every time it loops rather than modifying them. Move them outside the loop, like so:

```
package comp1skeleton2015;

class InputOutput
{

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        AQAConsole2015 console = new AQAConsole2015();
        AQAWriteTextFile2015 writeAQA = new AQAWriteTextFile2015();
        AQAReadTextFile2015 readAQA = new AQAReadTextFile2015();
        String doProgram = "yes";

        String[] names;
        String fileOutput = "names.txt";
        int amountOfNames = 0;
        int amountOfNames2 = 0;
        int x = 0;
        names = new String[1];
        names[0] = "";

        while(doProgram.equals("yes"))
        {
            console.println("Would you like to: ");
            console.println("1 - Write names to a file ");
            console.println("2 - Read names from a file ");
            console.println("3 - Display these names ");
            int option = console.readInteger("Please enter the corresponding number for the option: ");

            switch (option)
            {   
                case 1:
                {
                    int numOfNames = console.readInteger("Please enter how many names you would like to enter ");
                    names = new String[numOfNames];
                    writeAQA.openFile(fileOutput);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++)
                    {
                        String temp = console.readLine("Enter name " + i + ".");
                        writeAQA.writeToTextFile(temp);
                    }
                    writeAQA.closeFile();
                }
                break;
                case 2:
                {
                    readAQA.openTextFile(fileOutput);
                    boolean continueLoop = true;

                    while(readAQA.readLine() != null)
                        amountOfNames = amountOfNames + 1;

                    console.println (amountOfNames);
                    readAQA.closeFile();
                    readAQA.openTextFile(fileOutput);
                    names = new String[amountOfNames];

                    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfNames; i++)
                        names[i] = readAQA.readLine();
                    amountOfNames2 = amountOfNames;
                    readAQA.closeFile();
                }
                break;
                case 3:
                {
                    console.println (amountOfNames2);
                    console.println(names[1]);
                    for(int y = 0; y < amountOfNames; y++)
                        console.println(y + ": " + names[y]);
                }
                break;
                default:
                {   
                    console.println("You have entered an incorrect option, please try again");
                }
                break;

            }
            //doProgram = console.readLine("yes to continue");
        }
    }
}
```